# How to Save the optins in a text file without disturbing the email notif

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, email

I am using a custom optin page with a form , I want to tweak it a little bit,

- I want to save all the optins on a txt file on the server without
  disturbing the other functions of the form.
- 2nd thing I want is to show a custom Page after the optin form is
  submitted.

Currently the form works like this
**USER SUBMITS > PAGE REFRESHES FOR HIM > I GET AN EMAIL WITH THE SUBMITTED DATA.**

Here is the form code

```
<div class="form fix ">
                    <p class="form-text">Fill This Out and See Your <br>Timeshare Report</p>
                    <form name="contactform" action="mail-script.php" method="POST">
                        <label for="fname">First Name:
                            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="lname">Last Name:
                            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="email">Email Address:
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="phone">Phone Number:
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="phone">Alternate Phone:
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="aphone" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="resort">Resort Name:
                            <input type="text" name="resort" id="resort" />
                        </label><br>
                        <label for="amount">Amount Owed? $:
                            <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" />
                            <p style="font-size: 12px !important;margin-top: -14px;padding-right: 30px;text-align:right;">
                            If Paid Off Leave Zero, Else Put Amount</p>
                        </label><br>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <div class="check-text fix">
                                <p>I'm Considering To</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="check-one fix">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="sell"/> Sell It <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="buy"/> Buy It <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="rent "/> Rent  It 
                            </div>
                            <div class="check-two fix">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="cancel"/> Cancel Mortgage <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="ownership"/> End Ownership <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="give"/> Give It Back
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                                 <p class="captcha">
                            <img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' ><br>
                            <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label><br>
                            <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text"><br>
                            <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small>
                        </p>
                        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="" />
                        <p class="submit-text">Ensure all fields are completed and correct, allowing you more benefits, while preventing abuse of our data.</p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the mail script which sends me the email

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */

$myemail  = "**MYEMAIL**";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$fname    = check_input($_POST['fname'], "Enter your first name");
$lname    = check_input($_POST['lname'], "Enter your last name");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$phone    = check_input($_POST['phone']);
$resort   = check_input($_POST['resort']);
$amount   = check_input($_POST['amount']);
$call     = check_input($_POST['call']);

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:


First Name : $fname
Last Name : $lname
E-mail: $email
Phone : $phone
Resort: $resort
Amount: $amount
Call  : $call

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: index.html');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
if (strtolower($_POST['code']) != 'mycode') {die('Wrong access code');}
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Here is the online url of the page http://timesharesgroup.com/sell/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this code to your script after all the validation is done:

```
$text = "$fname\n$lname\n$email\n$phone\n$resort\n$amount\n$call\n\n";
file_put_contents('file.txt', $text, FILE_APPEND);
```

OR even better csv file:

```
$fields = array($fname,$lname,$email,$phone,$resort,$amount,$call);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After all validation , You mean before this
/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

Comment: it worked but it is only saving 1 at a time , I submitted the form once and the data got saved, I then resubmitted the form with diff details and the old one is gone now new one is there.. I want all optins recorded , Can You help a little more please

Comment: I also tried the cvs code and it is returning an empty cvs file

Comment: try the updated code, there is a flag for file_put_contents to append rather than overwrite the content. and the second method didnt have the append `a` it had `w`